# Auto-fill DTO fields with other data than request body data

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a class `CreateFolderDto` with two readonly fields:

```
export class CreateFolderDto {
    public readonly name: string
    public readonly user_id: number
}
```

I have a controller which is:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@Post()
public create(@Request() req, @Body() createFolderDto: CreateFolderDto) {
    return this.folderService.create(createFolderDto)
}
```

The request send to my controller is a good one, I only send the `name` in `json` format with an `accessToken` in the header. The `accessToken` permit me to get my `user_id` from the request with `req.user.id`.

The DTO field `user_id` is not automatically filled. I would like to fill it automatically.

Is it a way to auto-fill my `createFolderDto.user_id` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Body` only wraps actual request body into instance of the `CreateFolderDto` class. As the body which comes to your endpoint has no such a field, you need to add it manually.

Normally, aggregated fields could be added with custom constructor of your DTO:

```
export class CreateFolderDto {
    public readonly name: string
    public readonly session_uuid: string

    constructor(bodyValue: any = {}) {
       this.name = bodyValue.name
       this.session_uuid = generateUuid()
    }
}
```

But in your case, `user` is attached to `request` itself, so I believe you have the following options:

1. Check out your code which attaches the `user` to request itself. If you are using JWT Auth described in NestJS docs, you cannot do this that way.
2. You can write custom Interceptor:

```
Injectable()
export class ExtendBodyWithUserId implements NestInterceptor {
  async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    request.body.user_id = request.user
    return next.handle()
  }
}

// usage
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@UseInterceptors(ExtendBodyWithUserId)
@Post()
public create(@Request() req, @Body() createFolderDto: CreateFolderDto) {
    return this.folderService.create(createFolderDto)
}
```

Last but not least, some personal recommendation. Consider how much you will use this interceptor as an extension, as too many of 'extras' like this bloat the codebase.

I would recommend to change the `folderService` signature to:
`create(createFolderDto: CreateFolderDto, user: User)`, where folder dto has only the name, without user-related entry. You keep the consistency, separation and clear intentions. In the implementation of `create` you can just pass `user.id` further.
And going this way, you don't have to write custom interceptors.

Pick your way and may the consistency in your codebase be with you!